# jQuery replace content instead of fade

Tags: jquery, fade

I am trying to have content replaced when a div is clicked.  I have achieved this kind of using jQuery but currently the content just stacks up instead of being replaced..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#link1").click(function(){
     $('#content1').fadeIn('slow');
  });
  $("#link2").click(function(){
     $('#content2').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
</script>

<a id="link1" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a id="link2" href="#">Link 2</a>

<div id="content1">
    This is the test content for part 1
</div>
<div id="content2">
        This is the test content for part 2
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wqc9N/

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the content divs `position: absolute` and then put them inside a `position: relative` container. Try this:

```
.content-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
.content-container div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```js
$("#link1").click(function () {
    $('#content1').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#content2').fadeOut('slow');
});
$("#link2").click(function () {
    $('#content1').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#content2').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wqc9N/2/)

---

To reduce the amount of maintenance required when adding/removing links, try an approach like the following which uses classes to make elements more generic, and `data` attributes to maintain the connection between related elements.

```
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content1">Link 1</a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content2">Link 2</a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3">Link 3</a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content4">Link 4</a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content5">Link 5</a>

<div class="content-container">
    <div id="content1">This is the test content for part 1</div>
    <div id="content2">This is the test content for part 2</div>
    <div id="content3">This is the test content for part 3</div>
    <div id="content4">This is the test content for part 4</div>
    <div id="content5">This is the test content for part 5</div>
</div>
```

```js
$(".link").click(function() {
    $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

[**More extensible update**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wqc9N/6/)

Comment: This seems to work great, but how would it stand up if I had say 10 links instead of just two?

Comment: @fightstarr20 see my update. I made it much easier to maintain through the use of generic classes and data attributes. It will now automatically work for x amount of links.

Comment: Thanks for this it works great, the only issue I have left now is that when there is content above then it jumps to the top every time you click a reveal link - http://jsfiddle.net/Wqc9N/8/

Comment: @fightstarr20 you need to add `preventDefault()` within the handler: http://jsfiddle.net/Wqc9N/60/

Answer (score 1):

You have to hide the previous content. I added a class to your divs of `fadeContent`, then placed the `fadeIn` inside the `fadeOut` callback:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wqc9N/5/

Code:

```
$("#link1").click(function(){
    $(".fadeContent").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $('#content1').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
$("#link2").click(function(){
    $(".fadeContent").fadeOut("slow", function() { 
        $('#content2').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the other element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#link1").click(function(){
     $('#content1').fadeIn('slow');
     $('#content2').fadeOut('slow');
  });
  $("#link2").click(function(){
     $('#content2').fadeIn('slow');
     $('#content1').fadeOut('slow');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wqc9N/4/) I've added div `#content` instead of `#content1` and `#content2`

```
content = new Array(); // array to hold your content
content[1] = 'This is the test content for part 1';
content[2] = 'This is the test content for part 2';

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#link1").click(function(){
     $('#content').html(content[1]) // click link1 load content[1]
  });
  $("#link2").click(function(){
     $('#content').html(content[2]) // click link2 load content[2]
  });
});
```

I recommend adding a class to all the links to attach the event to all of them at once.